# Filtering or Ordering API request in query parameter

Tags: python, json, api, get, request

I am making a get request to a RESTful API using python. No issues interfacing with the API using the following format:

```
activities = requests.get("url/activities",headers=headers).json()
```

According to API documentation, I should be able to order and/or filter the request by "sending the request with the query parameter set in the url." These ar the examples given:

```
/activities?q={"name": "Test"}
or
/activities?order={"field": "asc"}
```

However when I make a request in the format:

```
activities = requests.get("url/activities?q={'name': 'Test'}",headers=headers).json()

or

activities = requests.get("url/activities?order={'field': 'asc'}",headers=headers).json()

print(activities)
```

I get:

```
{'type': 'Invalid Request error', 'code': 400, 'message': 'Search query must be json'}
or
{'type': 'Invalid Request error', 'code': 400, 'message': 'Order must be json'}
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to make the query or order json. I can't find anything else on the API documentation that suggests making the request any other way. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
"url/activities?q={'name': 'Test'}"
```

`{'name': 'Test'}` is not a valid JSON. JSON only recognize double quotes.

Similarly with the other query.

Comment: @AfredTX glad to hear that it helps. If my answer solved your problem, please do not forget to mark my answer as the solution (click on the white checkmark to turn it green). This is the expected conduct of StackOverflow/StackExchange members.

Answer (score 0):

about your speaking:

```
activities = requests.get("url/activities?q{'name':'Test'}",headers=headers).json()

or

activities=requests.get("url/activitiesorder{'field':'asc'}",headers=headers).json()
```

URL couldn't be like that `"url/activitiesorder{'field':'asc'}"` now url should become pure url and if you want to add some additional params you can do that like so:

```
import requests

url = "https://website.com/activities"
headers = {'name':'test'}

activities = requests.get(url, headers).json()

print(activities)
```

to know more:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: It's what the documentation for the API specified. Yes, it's a bad practice, but OP likely cannot change that and have to make do with how the API implementor specified.